# Where can I find a list of accessories I've allowed to connect to Mac

Tags: usb, accessories

There is a feature that asks user to allow new accessory to connect via usb/thunderbolt.
Official documentation is [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/allow-accessories-to-connect-mchlf779ae93/mac).

Is there a way to find what accessories are allowed and how to remove previously allowed accessory?

Comment: The article in the link you provided states "... a new USB or Thunderbolt devices and SD cards that you connect to your Mac". That's the 'allowed' list, not sure what more you'd need on that?

Comment: @fsb I'm looking to remove devices that I no longer use

Comment: What steps have you tried already?